# Python code getting error while execution

Tags: python

I am learning python as a beginner, and am executing a piece of code below:

Code1:

```
inp=input("Enter the number between 5 to 9:")

if (int(inp)<=5 or int(inp)>=9):

   raise ValueError ("Number should be between 5 to 9")

elif inp=="Quit":
  print("You Quit")
```

But I am getting error running above code when I enter "Quit" as an input. While the below code is running fine:

Code 2:

```
inp = input("Enter any value between 5 and 9 : ")

if inp == "Quit":

    print("You Quit")

elif (int(inp) <= 5 or int(inp) >=9):

    raise ValueError("Value should be between 5 and 9")
```

I would be highly obliged if you can make me understand of the error in the Code1.

Thank you!!!!

I tried a python code and am getting an error. I am expecting if someone can make me understand my mistake. in the code.

Comment: (1) Write a more meaningful title. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Stack%20Overflow%20only%20accepts%20certain,it%20will%20likely%20be%20closed)

Comment: If the input is 'Quit' you will get a ValueError exception when you call *int()*

Comment: You should have read the error. The message `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Quit'` seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

In the first `if` statement, you are trying to cast "Quit" into an integer. You can overcome this by simply putting the `elif` part as the `if`, and the conditions that require numbers, to be the subsequent conditions.

Example:

```
if inp == 'Quit':
    print("You Quit")
elif ......:
  # Other stuff
```

The problem occurs because Python is trying to convert "Quit" into an integer when you have `int(inp)` but the value of `inp` is "Quit"

`int("0")` will result in an integer value of `0`, but there's no way for the interpreter to convert `int("Quit")` into an integer value.

Hope that explains it! We all started somewhere, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you enter 'Quit', it's a string value. So the

```
if (int(inp)<=5 or int(inp)>=9):
```

gives you an error as the program can't process the value 'Quit' as an integer.
The only solution I can think of is to use the 2nd code as here the

```
if (int(inp)<=5 or int(inp)>=9):
```

is processed after the program has checked if the input is 'Quit'

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously by krish, the error happens when int(inp) is executed as every input is a string by default.

You may use the new code below:

```
inp=input("Enter the number between 5 to 9:")

if inp == "Quit":
    print("Quit")
else:
    try:
        inp=int(inp)
        if inp<5 or inp>9:
            print("Number should be between 5 to 9")
        else:
            print(f"Number input is: {inp}")
    except:
        print("Input should be an integer.")
```

Hope the above helps in addition to the explanation by krish.
Btw, hope you noticed my correction on your operators as well (if it was your intention to include 5 and 9.)